# get_posts array 'between' not behaving

Tags: get-posts, meta-value

if I make the query of

```
        $apartments = get_posts( array ( 'post_type' => 'apartment','meta_key' => 'bedrooms','meta_value'=> array(4,12) , 'compare' => 'BETWEEN' , 'type' => 'NUMERIC'));
```

I only get 4 and 8 bedroom apartments.

if I make the query of

```
        $apartments = get_posts( array ( 'post_type' => 'apartment','meta_key' => 'bedrooms','meta_value'=> array(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) , 'compare' => 'IN' , 'type' => 'NUMERIC'));
```

I also get 7 bedroom ones...

Why is the top item not seeing the 7 bedroom apartments? Am I not using BETWEEN properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are looking at post IDs, you should be using meta_value_num instead of meta_value as your key. This will indicate to WP how to handle the comparison.

Comment: Wow, silly me - I thought 'type' => 'NUMERIC' would be telling WP how to handle the comparison. I will test and respond with findings soon. Thanks for your time @vancoder.

Comment: OK...so now that brings back everything between 4 and 12 - thanks @vancoder that's great! New issue imminent :)

Comment: No problem. You should start a new issue as a new post, and feel free to mark my answer correct.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to create a new post but can work around it anyway thanks to this piece of valuable info :)